# Sort content of .CSV after first appearance of number

Tags: powershell

i would like to sort my Server-list in quite an unusal way.
So far i managed to sort my CSV-file with Powershell like this:

```
import-csv path | sort-object Name | export-csv path -useculture -notypeinformation
```

->

```
Name,IP,...
Server100,stuff,...
Server200,stuff,...
Server300,stuff,...
vServer100,stuff,...
vServer200,stuff,...
vServer300,stuff,...
```

But i would really like to sort them like this:

```
Name,IP,...
Server100,stuff,...
vServer100,stuff,...
Server200,stuff,...
vServer200,stuff,...
Server300,stuff,...
vServer300,stuff,...
```

Read something about regex, but i'm quite new to scripting and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a scriptblock or a calculated property definition as the `-Property` argument:

```
Import-Csv $path |Sort-Object { +$($_.Name -replace '\D') }, Name |...
```

The regex operation `$_.Name -replace '\D'` will take the value of the `Name` property (eg. `vServer100`) and remove any non-digits.
The `+` in front of the subexpression converts the resulting string (eg. `"100"`) to a number (eg. `100`).

After sorting on this number, `Sort-Object` will then order by `Name`, so `ServerXXX` appears before `vServerXXX`